# background detection in frames

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, tensor, yolo

Is there any way to check for background before detecting the object by using yolo algorithm.For example if the background has white crossing lines,then draw the contour for person detection.Is this is possible?

Comment: Can you give an example and explain the question more?*

Comment: My project is about detecting pedestrian who are using zebra crossing.I implemented this by using yolo algorithm where for the class person alone draw rectangular boxes to detect human.But now the problem is it detects every person who are walking on the road .I need human alone who are using zebra crossing.So I have a idea that before drawing the contour for the human just check for background having zebra crossing or not.Is it possible or is there any new way since I am new to this?

Comment: Try to update ur question instead of commenting

Comment: so you want to detect a zebra crossing? Try to find an appropriate algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by detecting humans and zebra crossing, and filter out the boxes that are not close or doesn't intersect with the zebra crossing bounding box using some rules.

Human detection can be done using Yolo. For detecting crosswalks, there is a lot of implementation on the internet, one of them is in [this](https://github.com/nis1/Crosswalk-Recognition) github repo